# Failed to start Rotate log files

Tags: 20.04

Each my syslog file (and each new syslog) begins from this strings:

```
localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2001.0" x-pid="451" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
localhost systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
localhost systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Rotate log files.
```

I have ubuntu 20 as VM on google cloud.
How fix this errors? Thanks.

upd: output for systemctl status logrotate.service

```
● logrotate.service - Rotate log files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● logrotate.timer
       Docs: man:logrotate(8)
             man:logrotate.conf(5)
```

Comment: Updated question with complete output.

Comment: This sort of thing can happen if you have logs that rotate outside of `/var/log`. Do you have logs for a service such as nginx, Apache, or something else being written outside of `/var/log`? 

Comment: Oh.. Its too difficult question for me.
I have instance on google cloud with clean Ubuntu 20. After I installed OpenLiteSpeed with cyberpanel. From cyberpanel I also installed Redis with backend (phpredis).

Comment: looks like I have logs outside /var/log
Litespeed logs /usr/local/lsws/logs/error.log

Comment: What I should do to fix this issue if I have have logs outside /var/log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your Litespeed logs in a location outside of `/var/log`, then the log rotation service will not have write access to the files that need to rotate. You have two options to choose from:

1. Move your Litespeed logs to a directory in `/var/log`, such as `/var/log/litespeed`
2. Update the `logrotate.service` file so the service can work with the log directory

Option 1 is pretty straightforward, so let's just look at the second item. This is how you can update the `logrotate.service` file:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Open the `logrotate.service` file as `root`:

   ```
   sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use a different editor if you prefer.*
2. Add the following line to the end of the file:

   ```
   ReadWritePaths=/usr/local/lsws/logs
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Restart the `logrotate` service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start logrotate
   ```

   ***Note:** There is no output to this command.*

---

#### Why?

In the `logrotate.service` file is a line that reads `ProtectSystem=full`. When `ProtectSystem` is set as `full` it will mount everything as readonly *except* the directory where logs are stored on the system, such as `/var/log`. By adding additional directories via `ReadWritePaths` you allow the service to use those locations without limitations.

If you're *really* interested in learning more about this, [the documentation breaks everything down in detail](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) ... though it is a rather dry read.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is very clear and helped me

Comment: Where is the list of logs that `logrotate` is trying to rotate?  I gather that looking outside of `/var/log` is what's making it fail to start?  How does it know to look outside of `/var/log`?  I've got lots of logs, and I couldn't even say where they all are.  If `logrotate` somehow has a list of all of this, where can I find it?  (I know things like `transmission` and `signal` log somewhere in my home directory, but I'm sure there's other stuff.)

Comment: On my system, the error appeared out of the blue when it had been working. However, trying the answer here did not solve it so it was apparently triggered by something else. When I try to restart the service it gives: `Job for logrotate.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status logrotate.service" and "journalctl -xeu logrotate.service" for details.` Running `journalctl -xeu logrotate.service` shows the same errors, all of which were today.